# is there a jobboard in civiCRM

Tags: webform-civicrm, php

new to civiCRM;-)

is there a jobboard in civiCRM

or to ask it in other words: does civiCRM  has a board constructed more in the realm of an Applicant Tracking System OR does it allow to function as a jobboard:

It might help if i describe a user scenario as well eg

**User A** want to list a job. They need to specify the Salary, Location, Skills required etc.

**User B** wants to find a job. They want to be able to search by Skilll, Location, Salary, etc

does civiCRM accomplish this?

Comment: Hi - what CMS are you using, as a Drupal answer might differ to a WP one.

Comment: running WP - but in earlier times i have installed drupal also. Look forward to hear from you again

Comment: sorry but my answer would be for a drupal setting

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'job board' feature as such. You could have a look at [CiviHR](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civihr) but I don't recall it being a place where people could advertise their own jobs.

If I had to do this, on Drupal, I would be using Drupal Webforms that would generate Activities which would then be displayed in a Drupal View with links that would take the 'applicant' to another Drupal Webform where they would generate another Activity that was somehow referencing the 'job position'.

Not much help to you directly but hope this gets the conversation started.

Comment: many many thanks - btw;: what about the fully fledged jobberbase - unfortunatly it is not under active develoment at the moment

Comment: i am not sure i really understand your comment. but no, there is no fully fledged jobber board.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a Drupal thing. You'd have a content type "job listing".

You should then use CiviCRM to handle the communications that can be sent to different job hunters by different job listers.

This sounds like it would function in a similar way to Future First's custo. Please feel free to ask me for further help and details at CiviFirst.com

Answer (score 0):

The CiviGrant component could be a good fit (with a few custom fields). Where the 'grant' is a job offer, and people could submit their application.